# Get ApplePay card info to pay in external system

Tags: applepay

Our customers want to apply the following scenario for the app:

1. The user taps "Pay" in the app.
2. The app (or backend) gets the card info from the user's ApplePay account.
3. Card info is being used to perform a payment in another payment system.

I'm 90% sure Apple doesn't let to do this, but I can't find any docs.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a payment system like Apple Pay that the merchant *doesn't* get the customer's credit card data? Apart from that, it's Apple... plus they would lose their 30% commission if they allowed this, no?

Comment: @Pekka웃 right. I need to be 100% sure and find some docs though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible: it goes against the whole point of having a payment system that obscures payment information from the merchant. Plus there's a million business reasons for the payment provider not to do this (and especially Apple, given that your client's requirement is likely to circumvent the huge commission they take on in-app purchases.)

There don't seem to be any docs on this (probably because it is so obvious that it's not an option) but there is this on the [official Apple Pay website:](http://www.apple.com/apple-pay/)

> **Your card number is never stored on your device, and when you pay your debit or credit card numbers are never sent to merchants.** Apple Pay assigns a unique number for each purchase, so your payments stay private and secure.

Comment: Thank you sir. They also told they had seen some info about "decoding the payment info" and thought that is what they need. I think it's about decoding the final purchase info encoded by Apple. Is it possible to decode it?

Comment: @SergeyMetlov I'm not sure. This document talks about decrypting payment tokens, perhaps that's what they mean? https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Getting-Started-with-Apple-Pay.pdf

Comment: I think yes. Thanks for starter info! I can go on digging it now myself.